# Angular material floating add button like in gmail

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, ngcordova

how do I achieve something like below with angular material

[image]

Comment: Did my answer help

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`ng-material-floating-button`](https://github.com/nobitagit/ng-material-floating-button)

```
<nav mfb-menu position="br" effect="zoomin" label="hover here"
     active-icon="ion-edit" resting-icon="ion-plus-round"
     toggling-method="click">
  <button mfb-button icon="paper-airplane" label="menu item"></button>
</nav>
```